# customising tooltip design in echarts with react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, charts, echarts

I'm working on a chart using echarts library with antd and react and I have to follow a specific tooltip design as below :

[image: expected tooltip]

what I could do is :

[image: actual tooltip]

tooltip implementation :

```
 const chartOptions = {


    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item',
        responsive: true,
        position: 'top',
        formatter: '{c}',
        backgroundColor: '#fafcfe',
        borderColor: '#c8e2f7',
        borderWidth: '0.8',
        textStyle: {
            color: '#5d6f80'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        data: xdata,
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'value',
        position: 'right',
    },
    series: [{
        data: data1,
        type: 'line',
        name: 'data1',
    },
    {
        data: data2,
        type: 'line',
        name: 'data2',
    } ] 
}
```

is there any way to add the down arrow and the link ( baby blue line between the tooltip and symbol)

css solution is acceptable but I'm beginner in css and frontend development in general

any suggestion would be helpful,
thank you

Answer (score 1):

To add that vertical axis line, you can simply change to `trigger: 'axis'`. Beware that `position: 'top'` does not work with this option, so you would have to change it to something like this:

```
position: function (point) {
    return [point[0], '20%'];
    // if u wanna center it to the line, then u could do something like
    // [point[0] - width_of_tooltip / 2, '20%']
}, ...
```

Regarding the down arrow, I see two options:

Change the formatter option to a function:

```
formatter: function (params) {
        return `<div class="tooltip">${params[0]}</div>`;
    }, ...
```

and then you can create the arrow with css, assigned to that `tooltip` class (see the example under *Tooltip Arrows* here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp).

Other option, would be to manually add a background image of a tooltip arrow and assign it through the `extraCssText` option, like this:

```
tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    extraCssText: "background-image: url(https://f0.pngfuel.com/png/287/216/white-box-illustration-png-clip-art.png);background-size:cover;min-height:100px;",
    ...
}
```

there you can add more css options to make it look like you want (I just chose a random bubble text box).
I'd personally like the first option better. Good luck!

Comment: when I set (trigger: 'axis') it just display the tooltip of first series . Is there another solution to display the tooltip of both series data  separately since I'm using two different line chart? with (trigger: 'axis')?

Comment: `trigger: 'axis'` has all the values of the series in its `params` argument, so you can display every series, but all in one tooltip.
Other option would be to keep `trigger: 'item'`, and then add axisPointer `tooltip: { trigger: 'item', axisPointer: { type: 'cross', crossStyle: { type: 'solid' } } }`
but that will show both x and y axis lines.